# extract the node IP without parsing the output of ifconfig

Tags: linux, awk, grep

The output of ifconfig in my machine looks like:

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    ether 3c:a8:2a:22:64:dc  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 7574600  bytes 945219457 (901.4 MiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 10  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
    device interrupt 16

eth1: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 3c:a8:2a:22:64:dd  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 17

eth2: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.25.26.78  netmask 255.255.254.0  broadcast 10.25.27.255
        inet6 fe80::8edc:d4ff:feab:48a0  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 8c:dc:d4:ab:48:a0  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1459110828  bytes 2115198897739 (1.9 TiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 32460  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1527389441  bytes 2229468090451 (2.0 TiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eth3: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 3c:a8:2a:22:64:de  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 16

eth4: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 3c:a8:2a:22:64:df  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 17

eth5: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 8c:dc:d4:ab:48:a1  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eth6: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 8c:dc:d4:a8:a0:e8  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eth7: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 8c:dc:d4:a8:a0:e9  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 77128853  bytes 11309319030 (10.5 GiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 77128853  bytes 11309319030 (10.5 GiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Since I want to extract IP from eth2 (different nodes can also have IP in eth2, eth5 etc). To generalize, I extracted the IP as:

```
/sbin/ifconfig|grep 'inet addr'|grep -v '127.0.0.1'|head -1|awk '{print $2}'|awk -F':' '{print $2}'
```

Still, I am getting output as empty string. What am I going wrong?

I want to extract the ip, where we have inet and netmask provided AND the inet should not be 127.0.0.1.

Comment: FYI `grep 'inet addr'|grep -v '127.0.0.1'|head -1|awk '{print $2}'|awk -F':' '{print $2}'` can be reduced to a single awk command: `awk '/inet addr/ && !/127.0.0.1/{split($2,a,/:/); print a[2]; exit}'`. I'm not saying that's the correct program to do what you want (in particular the unescaped `.`s in your regexp are clearly wrong), just showing how to write that with 1 command instead of 5 commands plus 4 pipes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ifconfig | egrep 'inet |netmask|broadcast' | grep -v '127.0.0.1' | awk '{print $2}' |awk '{print $1}'

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, if you don't want to parse the ifconfig's output you can use

```
hostname -i
```

It will provide the IP address assigned to your hostname.

If you want parse the above output and look for only for IPv4 address you can try this one:

```
cat test.txt |grep 'inet'|grep -v '127.0.0.1' | awk '{ print $2 }' | grep -oE "\b((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\b"
```

Answer (score 0):

> What am I going wrong?

You are grepping for *inet addr*…

---

Looks for ip that is not localhost on line with inet and netmask.

```
$ ifconfig | grep -oP 'inet \K(?!127\.0\.0\.1)[0-9.]+(?=.*netmask [0-9.]+)'
10.25.26.78
```

Uses PRCE regex with [\K](https://www.regular-expressions.info/keep.html) and [lookaheads](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to extract IP address of a host.

`hostname -i | cut -d' ' -f2`

`gethostip $HOSTNAME | cut -d' ' -f2`

If you still want to query the network interfaces, you should use `ip` instead of `ifconfig`.

`ip -o -f inet addr show scope global | awk -F'[ /]+' '{print $4}'`

Or

`ip -o -f inet addr show scope global | sed -n 's/.*inet \([^\/]*\)\/.*/\1/p'`

In your specific case, you only want to extract IP address of eth2. Instead of `scope global` you will use `dev eth2`.

`ip -o -f inet addr show dev eth2 | awk -F'[ /]+' '{print $4}'`